# how can I declare a slice of chan (channels) in func

Tags: go, slice, channel

I'm trying to write function like this, but I can't declare slice of channels

```
func fanIn(set <-[]chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)

    for i := range set {
        go func() { for {c <-set[i]} }()
    }
    return c
}
```

is it possible in Go to have a slice of channels as argument?

example of call

```
set := [2]chan string{mylib.Boring("Joe"), mylib.Boring("Ann")}
c := fanIn(set)
```

if I can do this

```
func fanIn(input1, input2 <-chan string) <-chan string {
```

I assume that it should be possible to have slice or array of "<-chan string"

**updated:**

```
func fanIn(set []<-chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)

    for i := range set {
        go func() {
            for {
                x := <-set[i]
                c <- x
            }
        }()
    }

    return c
}

func main() {
    set := []<-chan string{mylib.Boring("Joe"), mylib.Boring("Ann"), mylib.Boring("Max")}
    c := fanIn(set)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
    fmt.Println("You're boring: I'm leaving.")
}
```

Comment: You should rarely be returning channels from your public API, instead take a channel as argument that you send into. You can use this single channel in all of your Boring calls and won't even need the fanIn.

Comment: You could also use https://godoc.org/github.com/eapache/channels#Multiplex which uses a `select` to avoid spawning an entire goroutine for each input channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the syntax in your function a bit, it compiles now:

```
func fanIn(set []<-chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)


    for i := range set {
        // here is the main change - you receive from one channel and send to one.
        // the way you wrote it, you're sending the channel itself to the other channel
        go func() { for {c <- <- set[i]} }()
    }
    return c
}
```

BTW for the sake of readability, I'd write it as:

```
    go func() {
        for {
            x := <-set[i]
            c <- x
        }
    }()
```

EDIT: Your original code had the problem of using `set[i]` inside the goroutine, causing them all to read from the last channel. here's a fixed version:

```
func fanIn(set []<-chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)

    for i := range set {
        go func(in <-chan string) {
            for {
                x := <- in
                c <- x
            }
        }(set[i])
    }
    return c
}
```

Comment: great! Thanks alot! I see a strange picture. When I try to call fanIn(set) I got only last chan as result.

Comment: @qwertmax of course, that's because of `i`, let me fix my answer to be correct in this sense too

Comment: ahh, I messed it too. Thank you. Right now, is working perfect. You are the best.